# Get sum of business days in dataframe python with resample

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, resampling

I have a time-series where I want to get the sum the business day values for each week. A snapshot of the dataframe (`df`) used is shown below. Note that 2017-06-01 is a Friday and hence the days missing represent the weekend

I use `resample` to group the data by each week, and my aim is to get the sum. When I apply this function however I get results which I can't justify. I was expecting in the first row to get 0 which is the sum of the values contained in the first week, then 15 for the next week etc...

```
df_resampled = df.resample('W', label='left').sum()
df_resampled.head()
```

[image: Original DataFrame]
[image: Data after resampled]

Can someone explain to me what am I missing since it seems like I have not understood the resampling function correctly?

Comment: The date in your data looks a little inconsistent to me. Are they `yyyy-mm-dd`?

Comment: Hi I have just noticed that it is indeed inconsistent which might be what is causing the issue. I will sort and then update my question, thanks.

Comment: @prax1telis please post the table text (not an image)